# index out of range error -1 (== and !=)

Tags: java, string

im trying to make a method returns the number of words in phrase that are n letters long. I keep getting the string index out of range: -1 error

```
public static int nCount(String phrase, int n){
    String phrase3 = phrase;
    int phrase3Length = phrase3.length();
    int counter = 0;
    int currentWordLength = 0;
    int i = 0; //words checked
    int numberOfWords = words(phrase); //already have a method that checks for # of words

    while (numberOfWords > i) {

        while (phrase3.indexOf(" ") != 0) {
            phrase3 = phrase3.substring(1);   //line of trouble!! (index out of range -1)
            currentWordLength++;
        }

        while (phrase3.indexOf(" ") == 0) {
            phrase3 = phrase3.substring(1);
        } 

        if (currentWordLength == n) {
            counter++;
            i++;
            currentWordLength = 0;
        } else {
            i++;
            currentWordLength = 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't paraphrase error messages. Copy it exactly.

Comment: Why not share the stack trace of the error with us?... (that's another $1 to my "I get and error but I'm not including it" fund)

Comment: phrase3 = phrase3.substring(1); can you expalin this line plz?

Answer (score 0):

When phrase3 is empty string you will get an error.

```
phrase3.indexOf(" ") == -1 != 0
```

so this condition passes.

Then substring function fails.

Answer (score 0):

They are two problems with your *trouble line*.

- In Java String index starts at 0.  When your String has less than 1 character you get the error `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.
- Like Petar wrote, [`indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29) returns `-1` when no occurence is found in a String.  Based on what you seems to want to achieve you should probably check for `== -1` instead of `== 0`.

Also to simplify your code you should consider using [`split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29).